# why resolve this "b" == ([] +{})[!+[]<<!+[]]) to true

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

Can anyone explain this?

```js
console.log("b" == ([] +{})[!+[]<<!+[]])
```

I can imagine it has something to do with type conversion. but the `<<!` get me really confused

Comment: `([] +{})` === `'[object Object]'` ... `!+[]` === `true` ... ... `true<<true` === `1<<1` === `2` so `!+[]<<!+[]` === `2` ... `'[object Object][2]' === `'b'`

Comment: This is a lot of distinct operators and literals next to each other, so it is very hard to read. There is a similar JS compiler that creates valid JS out of 6 characters. It's algorithm explained on [the website](http://www.jsfuck.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break down the expression `([] +{})[!+[]<<!+[]]` to see how it resolves to `b`:

```
([] +{}) [!+[]<<!+[]]
```

The expression inside the left parentheses resolves to `[object Object]`, because both the `[]` and `{}` are coerced to strings (but the empty array, coerced to a string, is the empty string). So now you have

```
'[object Object]' [!+[]<<!+[]]
```

Break down the expression inside of the square brackets:

```
!+[]<<!+[]
```

Group using [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), and you get:

```
(!+[]) << (!+[])
```

And `!+[]` is `true`: `+[]` tries to convert the empty array to a number, but turning the empty array to a primitive results in the empty string, which is falsey, so the number is 0. `!` inverts the truthyness of that, resulting in `true`. So

```
(!+[]) << (!+[])
```

is equivalent to

```
true << true
```

Which is bitwise left-shift on their numeric equivalents:

```
1 << 1
```

which is 2. So

```
'[object Object]' [!+[]<<!+[]]
```

turns into

```
'[object Object]' [2]
```

or 'b`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's understand it step by

When you do arithmetic opreation on array it internally calls toString

```js
console.log([]+ 1, typeof ([] + 1))
```

so the `([]+{})` will result in `"[object Object]"`

```js
console.log([] +{})
```

When you use `+` unary operator which tries to change the operand to numeric values

```js
console.log(+[])
```

so now

```
(!+[] << !+[]) which is equal to ` 1 << 1`, so left shifts result in `2`
```

SO your simplified expression is

```js
console.log("b" == "[object Object]"[2] )
```

---

> This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to
>   the left. Excess bits shifted off to the left are discarded. Zero bits
>   are shifted in from the right. [`Left shift MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3C%3C_(Left_shift))

so 1 is represent as `01` in binary, so `1 << 1` will shift the binary by 1 position so it will become

```
`10`  -> in binary representation,
```

Which is equal to `2` in decimal format

```js
console.log(1<<1)
console.log((2).toString(2))
console.log(parseInt("10",2))
```